# Gstreamer rtsp receiving from ipcamera

Tags: tcp, gstreamer, rtsp, ip-camera

I have cheap ip camera based on Ambarella soc, and I'm trying to recive rtsp stream from it.
It works with ffmpeg

```
ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.155.160:80/0
```

but when I'm trying to get it with gstreamer

```
gst-launch-1.0 -m tcpclientsrc rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.155.160 port=80 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

I have a problem:

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got message #0 from element "streamsynchronizer0" (state-changed): GstMessageSta
teChanged, old-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_NULL, new-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_REA
DY, pending-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING;
Got message #1 from element "playsink" (state-changed): GstMessageStateChanged,
old-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_NULL, new-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_READY, pending
-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING;
Got message #2 from element "playbin0" (state-changed): GstMessageStateChanged,
old-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_NULL, new-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_READY, pending
-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_PAUSED;
Got message #6 from element "streamsynchronizer0" (state-changed): GstMessageSta
teChanged, old-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_READY, new-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_PA
USED, pending-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING;
Got message #7 from element "uridecodebin0" (state-changed): GstMessageStateChan
ged, old-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_NULL, new-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_READY, pe
nding-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_PAUSED;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.155.160:80" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nv_omx_h264dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! queue ! xvimagesink
```

you can obtain the correct rtsp id from source code of the web browser, if you try to stream it there.